# Getting Data as chunks from Database to save memory

Tags: java

My problem is related to JDBC queries where the number of records in the Table is huge. The end goal is getting the data from DB in a streamed fashion where by you get the data chunk by chunk.

This is possible by creating Multiple SQL statements by key words such as LIMIT , OFFSET. But in this case there will be multiple DB calls which will cost more time.
Is there a way where by you do not load an entire result Set into memory & can get data in chunks without having additional DB calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you are getting data in chunks from the database, you will be doing multiple database calls. You won't be executing as many queries.

Second, yes it is possible. There is a DB concept known as a "cursor".

```
Connection cn = //..
// Very important - JDBC default is to commit after every statement
// which will cause DB to close the cursor
cn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement st = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TBL_FOO");

// Cache 50 rows at the client at a time
st.setFetchSize(50);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    // Move the cursor position forward - moving past cached rows triggers another fetch
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

Note, the database will have fetched all the rows when it executed the query, and the result set will occupy DB memory until you close the cursor. Remember, the DB is a shared resource.

Comment: In this case the Database table if it has 1 lakh rows, all of them are not fetched into the memory, only 50 are fetched at a time ,is that right?  The rest of the data is obtained using further Sql queries? I mean how does the JDBC driver get the Rest of the data?

Comment: And my main goal is to reduce the memory occupied by the application. Is that achieved here? Your last statement implied that all the rows are fetched. Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: Yes. As you iterate the result set in Java.

Comment: The database will fetch all of the rows, regardless. The question is, where is that memory occupied? You can limit the memory used by the client, but that means the server has to keep all of the rows in memory until the client is done. Does that mean you are reducing the memory used by the application? That depends on what you mean.

Comment: I understood that. But initially when the query is executed, only a chunk is retreived if you set the fetchSize. But as you iterate through the resultset as an when the fetchsize is surpassed the new chunk would be fetched. This sounds fine for my scenario, since all of the data is not fetched at once.

Comment: In my particular scenario, the rows fetched from DB and stored from the server is not a problem. We want to reduce the memory on the client side.